# Optimizing list processing in Scala

Tags: performance, scala, optimization, scala-collections

Right now processing a large amount of Json data coming from a Mixpanel API. With a small dataset, it's a breeze and the code below runs just fine. However, a large dataset takes a rather long time to process and we're starting to see timeouts because of it.

My Scala optimization skills are rather poor, so I am hoping someone can show a faster way to process the following with large data sets. Please do explain *why* since it will help my own understanding of Scala.

```
val people = parse[mp.data.Segmentation](o)
val list = people.data.values.map(b => 
  b._2.map(p => 
    Map(
      "id" -> p._1, 
      "activity" -> p._2.foldLeft(0)(_+_._2)
    )
  )
)
.flatten
.filter{ behavior => behavior("activity") != 0 }
.groupBy(o => o("id"))
.map{ case (k,v) => Map("id" -> k, "activity" -> v.map( o => o("activity").asInstanceOf[Int]).sum) }
```

And that `Segmentation` class:

```
case class Segmentation(
  val legend_size: Int,
  val data: Data
)

case class Data(
  val series: List[String],
  val values: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, Int]]]
)
```

Thanks for your help!

### Edit: sample data as requested

```
{"legend_size": 4, "data": {"series": ["2013-12-17", "2013-12-18", "2013-12-19", "2013-12-20", "2013-12-21", "2013-12-22", "2013-12-23", "2013-12-24", "2013-12-25", "2013-12-26", "2013-12-27", "2013-12-28", "2013-12-29", "2013-12-30", "2013-12-31", "2014-01-01", "2014-01-02", "2014-01-03", "2014-01-04", "2014-01-05", "2014-01-06"], "values": {"afef4ac12a21d5c4ef679c6507fe65cd": {"id:twitter.com:194436690": {"2013-12-20": 0, "2013-12-29": 0, "2013-12-28": 0, "2013-12-23": 0, "2013-12-22": 0, "2013-12-21": 1, "2013-12-25": 0, "2013-12-27": 0, "2013-12-26": 0, "2013-12-24": 0, "2013-12-31": 0, "2014-01-06": 0, "2014-01-04": 0, "2014-01-05": 0, "2014-01-02": 0, "2014-01-03": 0, "2014-01-01": 0, "2013-12-30": 0, "2013-12-17": 0, "2013-12-18": 0, "2013-12-19": 0}, "id:twitter.com:330103796": {"2013-12-20": 0, "2013-12-29": 0, "2013-12-28": 0, "2013-12-23": 0, "2013-12-22": 0, "2013-12-21": 0, "2013-12-25": 0, "2013-12-27": 0, "2013-12-26": 1, "2013-12-24": 0, "2013-12-31": 0, "2014-01-06": 0, "2014-01-04": 0, "2014-01-05": 0, "2014-01-02": 0, "2014-01-03": 0, "2014-01-01": 0, "2013-12-30": 0, "2013-12-17": 0, "2013-12-18": 0, "2013-12-19": 0}, "id:twitter.com:216664121": {"2013-12-20": 0, "2013-12-29": 0, "2013-12-28": 0, "2013-12-23": 1, "2013-12-22": 0, "2013-12-21": 0, "2013-12-25": 0, "2013-12-27": 0, "2013-12-26": 0, "2013-12-24": 0, "2013-12-31": 0, "2014-01-06": 0, "2014-01-04": 0, "2014-01-05": 0, "2014-01-02": 0, "2014-01-03": 0, "2014-01-01": 0, "2013-12-30": 0, "2013-12-17": 0, "2013-12-18": 0, "2013-12-19": 0}, "id:twitter.com:414117608": {"2013-12-20": 0, "2013-12-29": 0, "2013-12-28": 1, "2013-12-23": 0, "2013-12-22": 0, "2013-12-21": 0, "2013-12-25": 0, "2013-12-27": 0, "2013-12-26": 0, "2013-12-24": 0, "2013-12-31": 0, "2014-01-06": 0, "2014-01-04": 0, "2014-01-05": 0, "2014-01-02": 0, "2014-01-03": 0, "2014-01-01": 0, "2013-12-30": 0, "2013-12-17": 0, "2013-12-18": 0, "2013-12-19": 0}}}}}
```

To answer Millhouse's question, the intention is to sum up each date to provide a number that describes total volume of "activity" for each ID. The "ID" is formatted as `id:twitter.com:923842`.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a snippet of some of your test JSON data, and also explain what the intention is (looks like it's summing the `activity` value per-`id` ?)

Comment: Lack of free heap space can cause significant slowdown in case of large data. Use standard Java memory profiling tools to find out.

Comment: @millhouse sample data added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the full extent of your processing, what pipelines you have going on, what stress your server is under or what sort of threading profile you've set up to receive the information. However, assuming that you've correctly separated I/O from CPU bound tasks and what you've shown us is strictly CPU bound try simply adding `.par` to the very first Map.

```
people.data.values.par.map(b =>
```

as a first pass to see if you can get some performance gains. I don't see any specific ordering required of the processing which tells me it's ripe for parallelization.

### Edit

After playing around with parallelization, I would add that modifying the `TaskSupport` is helpful for this case. You can modify a parallelized collection's `tasksupport` as such:

```
import scala.collection.parallel._
val pc = mutable.ParArray(1, 2, 3)
pc.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(
  new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(2))
```

See http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.TaskSupport

Comment: interesting, didn't know about `par`. I would note that you'll need to call something like `.toList` to convert it back to a normal collection. Testing this now...

Comment: Editing answer to assist solution. Thanks, this was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestions that might help.

1. I would try to move the filter command as early in the program as
   possible. Since your data contains many dates with 0 activity you 
   would see improvements doing this. The best solution might be to
   test for this while parsing the json data. If this is not possible 
   make it the first statement.
2. The way I understand it you would like to end up with a way to look up a aggregate of
   the sums for a given id. I would suggest you represent this with a map from the id 
   to the aggregate. Also the scala List class has a sum function. 
   I came up with this code:

   > val originalList_IdToAggregate = people.data.values.map(p=> (p._2._1,
   >   p._2._2.sum) );

   It might not match your project directly, but I think it is almost what you need.
   If you need to make a map of this you just append toMap to the end.
3. If this doesn't give you enough speed you could create your own parser that aggregates 
   and filters while parsing only this kind of json. 
   Writing parsers is quite easy in scala if you are using the parser combinators. 
   Just keep in mind to throw away what you don't need as early as possible and not to make
   too many deep branches this should be a fast solution with a low memory footprint.
4. As for going parallel this can be a good idea. I don't know enough about 
   your application to tell you what is the best way, but it might be possible 
   to hide the computational cost of processing the data under the cost of 
   transporting the data. Try to balance parsing and io over multiple 
   threads and see if you can achieve this.